# Wrong location reading/bad accuracy on some devices

Tags: android, gps, location

I use the Google MAPS API to get the current user's location (GPS coordinates). But I have a strange problem:

In my Lenovo Android 4.2 the location quite accurate.

But in another device (LG G3s) the location is off by more than 400-500 meters.

And it's the same situation for different devices. In one - it's OK, in another wrong.

Here my code:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOCATION CHANGED\n"+
                    "LAT="+location.getLatitude()+"\n"+
                    "LON="+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GoogleApiClient connection has failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Maybe, I did something wrong ?

How can I get more accurate coordinates ?

**UPD:**
I tested GPS outside and coordinates quite accuracy.
But in house/office - coordinates wrong. User located in office, but app shows his location in the river, about 500-600m from office)

I think problem with my app, because user said that he runned Google Maps on his device and location not wrong..

Comment: Are you inside or outside when you're testing your GPS coordinates? The quality of GPS signal matters greatly on your location and also on the the quality of the GPS receivers. Not all are created equal.

Comment: Outside coordinates quite well. Please see my UPD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve by demaning that only GPS Provider is used.
Inside a building this would result in about 30 - 50m offset, when beeing near the window. This is better than the 500m network offset.

Comment: Thanks for response. But in building device can not get signal from satelites.. I need to give coordinates every n-minutes.

Comment: Then just give the last known location; inside a building there is no signal. And last known GPS better than current network

Comment: thanks for response, but if user launch app only in building ?

Answer (score 0):

400-500m is normal for network based location.  Likely they have GPS turned off.

Comment: Good guess at what the problem might be but as it stands the answer is more of a comment quality. I suggesting expanding your answer or deleting it and reposting as a comment.

Comment: But in Google Maps app location OK. Why?)